# 'Error: uncaught (in promise) missing number at position 0' in error handler in angular5

Tags: typescript, error-handling, angular5, angular-errorhandler

I am using `ErrorHandler` interface in my angular5 project to show the error message and log error in console. The problem is I am getting `Error: uncaught (in promise): Missing number at position 0` and `Cannot read property of undefined` when ever I click on `Submit` button of the details form, for all other `Submit` buttons I do not get this error.

Can any one please guide me why am I getting this error and how to handle it? Thanks.

```
// errors-handler.ts
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class ErrorsHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  handleError(error: any) {   
      if (error.error.message != undefined) {
         var errorMsg = error.error.message;
      } else {
         var errorMsg = "No description available";
      }
   }
}
```